# Как в Windows Forms создать нестандартный элемент управления?

Tags: c#, winforms

В Windows Forms нужно создать экранную клавиатуру с увеличением букв и считывание набранного текста из класса формы, и отображение его в отдельном текстовом окне.
Стандартные элементы управления нельзя использовать. Исключения кнопки. И вот вопрос, как создать нестандартный элемент управления и считывания текста в другую форму с помощью созданной клавиатуры?

Comment: Не совсем уверен, чего вы хотите, но судя по тому, что прочёл, вам нужно создать свою форму, которая эмулирует клавиатуру, которая будет обращаться к другой форме (например. к текстбоксу). Так?

Comment: Да, типо того. (//15 символов)

Comment: Ну так а в чём сложность?
Создаете форму(1) с кнопками > Запихиваете в кнопки логику [передачи данных в другую форму](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22471648/how-to-access-textbox-text-in-another-form)(2) > Подписываете форму(2) на эвент, при котором компонент этой формы (лейбл, например) меняется, что б её обновлять > ??? >Profit. Ну это так, абстрактно, не вдаваясь в конкретную реализацию.

Comment: Вот логика передачи не понятна, например передать нажатие кнопки "Q" в другую форму это что нужно писать?

Comment: У Вас есть 2 формы: Целевая(`Target`) и Клавиатура(`Keyboard`). 
У `Target` есть некий `label`.
При нажатии на кнопку Q в `Keyboard`, он обращается к `Target.label.Text`, меняя его(ну или добавляя в него что-либо). Примерно [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4823535/7568618).

Comment: У вас в одном вопросе несколько. Это не хорошо, их нужно задавать отдельно, это раз. Вопросы по учебным заданиям допустимы, но при условии, что в вопросе содержится код или, хотя бы, подробное описание вашей попытки решить данную проблему, это два. И три, что вы имеете ввиду под "нестандартным" контролом? Пока из текста задачи я не вижу причины дергать WinAPI напрямую или делать ручную отрисовку, нужно просто скомпоновать стандартные контролы в нужном порядке и прописать их поведение.